# HttpRequestMessage getting disposed after sending request

Tags: c#

I have a class in my program that calls an API, and every request goes through the following function to retry the request a few times in case of timeouts.

```
protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RetryIfExceptionAsync(string urlString, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpContent httpContent, byte exceptionRetries)
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;

    byte retries = exceptionRetries;
    while (retries != 0)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(urlString),
            Method = httpMethod,
            Content = httpContent
        };
        try
        {
            httpResponse = await Program.HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);  // <--- This is line 93
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException taskCanceledException)
        {
            if (!taskCanceledException.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Program.TimeoutDebugLog.Append(String.Format("{0} timeout, retries: {1}, url: {2}", httpMethod, retries, urlString));   //TimeoutDebugLog is a StringBuilder
                await Task.Delay(200);
                retries--;
                continue;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    if (httpResponse == null)
    {
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("TimeoutDebugLog.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append))
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(Program.TimeoutDebugLog.ToString());
        }
        Program.TimeoutDebugLog.Clear();
        throw new CustomHttpRequestException("Failed to obtain response after 5 attemps")
        {
            RequestUrl = urlString,
            RequestMethod = httpMethod,
            RequestContent = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

For some reason though I'm getting an `ObjectDiposedException` saying something like "Not possible to access discarted object objectname: System.Net.Http.StringContent". Here's is the stack trace pointing the exception is thrown at line 93, which I've indicated in the code:

```
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- end of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AuditLogsDownload.ConsoleApp.Net.ApiCall.<RetryIfExceptionAsync>d__6.MoveNext() at {filepath}:line 93
```

I've checked [the HttpClient source code at github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs), and there's a comment there saying `SendAsync()` used to dispose the content of the request but that is no longer the case. What am I missing? How can I work around this error? The fact that every class is a reference type in C# makes me unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: How did you instantiate `Program.HttpClient`?

Comment: What is the StatusCode? Are you using Https for the connection? How is HttpClient instantiated?

Comment: What's the version of your System.Net.Http dll? I'm running on version 4.2.0.0 and it works perfectly, no ObjectDiposedException. This could be the issue.

Comment: `saying something like` Please update your question with the actual message.

Comment: @Win , Jimi,  HttpClient is instantiated with the parameterless constructor, only altered property is timeout set to 30 seconds instead of the default 100 seconds. Yes I'm using https for the connection, but there's no status code as the exception mentioned only triggers if the request timedout (so no response was received).

Comment: @mjwills I say `saying something like` because my system is not in english and I had to translate the message. The meaning of the message is exactly the one stated here, that `StringContent` (the content I'm trying to send with `SendAsync`) got disposed somewhere, just the wording of the english message might be a little different

Comment: Https: you might need to exchange Cookies, but also to validate a Server certificate. Use an [HttpClientHandler()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(VS.110).aspx) to manage the Cookies. [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the SSL protocols you support, [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) (...)

Comment: to specify the server certificate validation callback used to validate the server certificate. Also, add a User Agent to the HttpClient headers. You can find reference code for all this in SO (a lot of references).

Comment: @Jimi I was sending requests to an API I built myself, I really doubt headers or certificates would be an issue. I've found the problem and the solution as stated in the answer I've posted below, but thanks for the help reagrdless.

Comment: What I wrote is about a generic context. If you try to access a resource through SSL, you code will have a very high probability to fail to retrieve anything because it's not supporting the SSL standard. This will possibly cause a TimeOut, when the Client/Server Handshake fails to find a resolution. The point is, why `SendAsync()` would fail? First thing, you look at the StatusCode of the response (if readable) or the Error Status of the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've been able to replicate the issue by disconnecting from the internet (to throw an exception on `SendAsync()`) and running the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent("Hi");
        while (true)
        {
            here:
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/post"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = content
            };
            try
            {
                var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                goto here;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the `HttpClient` source code I looked saying that "the request used to be discarted but no longer does" is the source code for the .NET Core `HttpClient`. In .NET framework (which is what I'm using) `HttpClient` still disposes the request when `SendAsync` throws an exception.

So I guess the way to fix this is to pass the string as a parameter rather than the `StringContent`, then make a new `StringContent` before every `SendAsync()`. Rather lame but is what I can think of right now.